# Precios variables en WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Me encuentro bloqueado en una tienda online que estoy realizando.

Se trata de 1 único producto pero variable. Las funciones nativas de WooCommerce no me permiten realizar lo solicitado. La cuestión es la siguiente:

Los usuarios deben marcar si quieren facturación mensual o anual y, en base a ello, cambiar el precio (esto puedo hacerlo)

Añadir un sobrecoste como "alta de licencia" con un importe exacto (las tasas de WooCommerce solo me permiten añadir un valor en % y al ser un precio variable, no me saca ese importe).

Necesito añadir un campo para que elijan la cantidad de usuarios que necesitan con el producto. Si son 6 el precio se mantiene, a partir de ahí suma 1€ si es facturación mensual y 10,80€ si es facturación anual por cada usuario a mayores.

Después, necesito habilitar un campo para establecer un valor (x) el cual sume al precio 750€*x.

¿Hay algún plugin que resuelva esto? Muchas gracias.